# vscode python environment manager can't recognize conda environment?

Tags: installation, anaconda, vscode-extensions, wsl-2

## Behaviour

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teRfe.jpg)

### Expected vs. Actual

#### Expected

Press the `+` button in "GLOBAL ENVIRONMENTS,Conda" and a Conda environment should be created after a few steps.

#### Actual

Press the `+` button but get "Install `conda` to create conda environments."

### Steps to reproduce:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda
```

And of course install this extension.

[Imgur](https://imgur.com/TAozzjt)

## Diagnostic data

- Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): 3.11.4
- Type of virtual environment used (e.g. conda, venv, virtualenv, etc.): Conda
- Value of the `python.languageServer` setting: Default

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CPUs | 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H (20 x 2688) |
| GPU Status | 2d_canvas: enabled<br>canvas_oop_rasterization: enabled_on<br>direct_rendering_display_compositor: disabled_off_ok<br>gpu_compositing: enabled<br>multiple_raster_threads: enabled_on<br>opengl: enabled_on<br>rasterization: enabled<br>raw_draw: disabled_off_ok<br>video_decode: enabled<br>video_encode: enabled<br>vulkan: disabled_off<br>webgl: enabled<br>webgl2: enabled<br>webgpu: enabled |
| Load (avg) | undefined |
| Memory (System) | 15.69GB (5.68GB free) |
| Process Argv | --crash-reporter-id a8854b56-824f-4d3f-8f2a-48ea46971635 |
| Screen Reader | no |
| VM | 33% |

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Remote | WSL: Ubuntu-22.04 |
| OS | Linux x64 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 |
| CPUs | 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H (20 x 2688) |
| Memory (System) | 7.60GB (6.03GB free) |
| VM | 0% |

For 100% I installed conda correctly in wsl. I can create conda environment using bash commands and the environment I created can be recongnized successfully by this extension. But I just can't create a conda environment by simply press the `+` button. Neither can I manage packages (I mean installing specificly) in conda environment, but I can manage packages when I select non-conda interpreters. (I checked network via wireshark and found there's no internet packages sending out when I was trying to search for packages using this extension)